# Using a function in the render state in ReactJS to append a div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I was messing around and creating a comment like tree structure, which works out fine except when I want to get into creating collapsing and expanding commenting trees. So far the display is well, it is displayed on my webpage in proper tree structure, just like reddit, however I want to build in a collapse and expand comments and subcomments feature. I have an idea of using jquery to appending a div as soon as it is finished rendering. What comes to mind when i think about it is:

```
         var childDiv = "#" + comment._id;
         var parentDiv = "#" + comment.pComment;


         $(parentDiv).append(childDiv);
```

This is my idea of appending divs together, where pComment holds the parentComments id, and I already establish my divs with the id of themselves as soon as they are mapped/rendered. However the issue is how do I tell my render function this is what I want to do at the end of each render mapping. I map a comment at a time, and I create the div there, so obviously it cant map to that div if it isnt there, and this is where I get lost. I tried out the idea with making it a onclick function and worked out great, but I would like for it to append on each mapping, and at the end of it after the div is rendered, so it appends the div's in correct order. I think there's alot of differents way to go about this but I'm not sure how.

```
render : function() {
      return( 

          <div>
          <ul className = "list-unstyled">
          {
          this.props.comments.map(function(comment) {
            return(


            //Right here is what I want to append to another div.
            <div id = {comment._id}>
            <div className = "userComments">
            //content
            </div>
            </div>
            )


            })
            }
              </ul>
              </div>
         )
    }
```

Generally my goal is to create a parent div, and append to it any div that holds its children.

I've tried doing `var x = $(parentDiv).append(childDiv);` and then I proceeded to call **{x}** in between the div so it would append it. For the parent case, pComment is defaulted to the id ROOT, every comment that is owned by that comment after has its 'pComment' value held by its owners id.

However doing so I get

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: traverseAllChildren(...): Encountered an invalid child; DOM elements are not valid children of React components.
```

Comment: it's generally a good idea to look over your post after posting it, to see if there's anything you need to clean up - in this case, formatting the code so it's easier for people to read and help you is probably a good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of thinking about *collapsing (v)* think about setting the state to *collapsed (adj)*. When the user clicks expand / hide, set a boolean. In your render function, check the boolean.

Something like this:

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { hidden: false } 
  },

  render: function () {
    return (<div class={ this.state.hidden && 'hidden' } onClick={ this.toggle }>
      { this.props.children }
    </div>)
  },

  toggle: function (ev) {
    this.setState({ hidden: !this.state.hidden })
  },
})
```

And in the css:

```
.hidden div { display: none; }
```

**Edit**: How to append divs

Stop thinking in verbs. You don't want to *append (v)* divs, you want divs to either be *present (adj)* or *absent (adj)*. You can use another boolean, or whatever conditional you'd like:

```
render: function () {
  return (<div>{ this.state.weWantDivs && this.renderDivs() }</div>)
}
```

**Edit**: How to put child view in parent view

Put the child elements in the parent element.

```
render: function () {
  return <Parent><Child></Child></Parent>
}
```

And in the parent element render special `children` property.

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <div>{ this.props.children }</div>
  }
})
```

Comment: I mean yea, that will help me with the collapsing so thanks, but how do I deal with the appending of divs?

Comment: Im still quite confused with your explanation, somewhere along the line I have to state that this child belongs to this parent though. I can't possibly do that in the jsx in the render can i? It seems like I can't wrap my head around this for some reason.

Comment: By rendering a component inside another component's `render` function, you are effectively establishing that relationship.

Comment: I understand it well, and I've gotten it to work thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should not imperatively modify the DOM with React. Call `this.setState` and allow React to modify the DOM.

Keep an object representing your comment structure near the top of your component hierarchy, when something change that would need to modify it, you can call `this.setState` the new/modified comment object.